# Get complete Map from Redis if a key contains a String

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I am able to add and get a particular user object from Redis I am adding object like this:

```
 private static final String USER_PREFIX = ":USER:";
 public void addUserToRedis(String serverName,User user) {
    redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(serverName + USER_PREFIX + user.getId(),  
   Integer.toString(user.getId()),user);    
    }
```

If a userId is 100 I am able to get by key: **SERVER1:USER:100** 
Now I want to retrieve all Users as `Map<String,List<User>>` , 
For example, get all users by this key **SERVER1:USER:**  
Is it possible ? Or I need to modify my **addUserToRedis** method? Please suggest me.

Comment: You can do a wildcard search. "SERVER:USER:*". Check pattern search in redis

Comment: It's working with wildcard searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I came up with this solution with wildcard search and avoiding KEYS, and here is my complete method:

```
  public Map<String, User> getUserMapFromRedis(String serverName){
    Map<String, User> users=new HashMap<>();
     RedisConnection redisConnection = null;
     try {
            redisConnection = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection();
           ScanOptions options = ScanOptions.scanOptions().match(serverName + USER_PREFIX+"*").build();
           Cursor<byte[]> scan = redisConnection.scan(options);
           while (scan.hasNext()) {
           byte[] next = scan.next();
           String key = new String(next, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
           String[] keyArray=key.split(":");
           String userId=keyArray[2];
           User user=//get User by userId From Redis
           users.put(userId, user);
           }
           try {
           scan.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          
      }
       }finally {
       redisConnection.close(); //Ensure closing this connection.
       }
     return users;
    }
```

Comment: KEYS would block redis server. if must, you can try using SCAN

Comment: @TuanAnhTran can you guide me that how to use with redisTemplate in this scenario, this will be very helpful

Comment: I dont use java but here's how to do it with nodejs https://stackoverflow.com/a/64007618/2688699

Comment: @TuanAnhTran I edited my answer to avoid using KEYS, now I am using SCAN. This one is fine?

Comment: yeah should be fine. you can test by creating few millions key and see for your self :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not using the "KEYS" command in production as this can severely impact REDIS latencies ([can even bring down the cluster if you have a large number of keys stored](https://swayamraina.dev/#/blogs/engineering/2018/redis-and-lua))

Instead, you would want to use a different command than plain GET/SET.

It would be better if you use a [Sets](https://redis.io/commands/sadd) or [Hashes](https://redis.io/commands/hset)

```
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd server1 user1 user2
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers server1
1) "user2"
2) "user1"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Using sets you can simply add your users to server keys and get the entire list of users on a server.

If you really need a map of `< server, list < users > >` you can use hashes with stringified user data and then convert it to actual `User` POJO at application layer

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset server2 user11 name
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hset server2 user13 name
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall server2
1) "user11"
2) "name"
3) "user13"
4) "name"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Also do note that keeping this much big data into a single key is not an ideal thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

i dont use java but here's how to use SCAN

```js
const Redis = require('ioredis')
const redis = new Redis()

async function main() {
    const stream = redis.scanStream({
        match: "*:user:*",
        count: 100,
    })

    stream.on("data", (resultKeys) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < resultKeys.length; i++) {
            // console.log(resultKeys[i])
            // do your things here
        }
    });
    stream.on("end", () => {
        console.log("all keys have been visited");
    });
}

main()
```